# Laptop shuts down completely, but then powers on automatically again

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, drivers, power-management, shutdown

I have upgraded my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 on my laptop recently. Everything on 12.04 worked perfectly, but now, when I choose to shutdown the laptop using either the GUI, or `sudo init 0` in the command line, it shuts down completely (screen and all LED's off, fans stopped, could hear hard drive shuts down), but then just powers up automatically again, and starts loading the OS. Using `sudo halt` or `sudo shutdown -h now` freezes on the splash screen.

I did install all the latest Ubuntu updates as of today. At first the wifi didn't work, which I fixed by installing the RT3290_u16 driver. I found that without this driver the PC shuts down and stays off, but then I have no wifi functionality. With the driver, the wifi works perfectly, but the laptop doesn't stays off.

I switched off any "Wake on LAN", "Wake on USB" and related options in the BIOS. I also modified the `/etc/default/grub` file with the `acpi=force apm=power_off` options. I also tried unplugging the AC charger just before shutting down.

I have tried scanning through the system logs, but to be honest, I don't really know what to look for.

The laptop with the problem is an HP ProBook 4540s.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here: [Reboot after shutdown (Ubuntu 14.04 (also 12.04); Dell latitude E7440)](//askubuntu.com/q/452750). Do you have a "Wake on LAN" option in the BIOS. If so, you can try turning it off.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all of the suggestions, but unfortunately nothing worked. I updated my question with everything I tried.

Answer (score 0):

OK since my previous answer wasn't on point I decided to edit it, here goes:
I don't own the laptop but I Googled the issue and as it turns out it's a common issue that isn't related to Ubuntu, according to this [thread from Tom's hardware](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2265203/laptop-shuts-automatically-turns-seconds.html) it was fixed by changing the charger.

Try a different charger and see if the problem persists, good luck.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. If you still dont have enough reputation to comment, limit to answer questions what dont need any kind of clarification or further information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I already tried that route and unfortunately did not work.